# Place subfigure caption top left in revtex4-2 template

Tags: captions, subfloats, revtex

I would like to place the `subfigure` captions at the top left of the images. There are a ton of questions like this here but they all use the `subcaption` package, which I **don't** want to do since my template is `revtex4-2`.

Here is a MWE. All looks good, except I want (i) and (ii) to be at the top left. If it matters, I will not be adding any actual caption to each subfigure, just want to label them via roman numerals.

**EDIT:** I use the `float` package as well in the non-MWE example, so leveraging `floatrow` will not work either!

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,aps,pre]{revtex4-2} 
\usepackage{graphicx, float}
\usepackage[FIGTOPCAP]{subfigure} 
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\roman{subfigure})}

\begin{document} 

\begin{figure*}[htb]
    \centering
    \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.35\linewidth]{example-image-a} \label{fig: a}}
    \hfill
    \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.35\linewidth]{example-image-b} \label{fig: b}}
    \caption{I want \subref{fig: a} and \subref{fig: b} to be placed at the top \textit{left}.} 
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```